# There was an authentication failure. "Failed to decode the S/MIME message. The S/MIME message may not be valid."

Tags: visual-studio-2010, biztalk, biztalk-2010

Created a simple *XMLreceive Pipeline* (added  XMLassembler with Document Schema and Envelope Schema) and *Passthru Send Pipeline*. Set "Allow non MIME Message" to TRUE, "Check revokation list" to "TRUE/FALSE" in MIME/SMIME Decoder.

Deployed to BizTalk 2010 Server (Windows Server 2008 R2 and Sql Server 2008 ).

Configured Receive and Send Ports in BizTalk server.  Getting the following error. I have tried by removing MIME/SMIME Decoder still same error

> There was a failure executing the receive pipeline: "Messaging.ReceivePurchaseOrders, Messaging, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b1e04cc8b8d2213c" Source: "MIME/SMIME decoder" Receive Port: "M6RcvPrt-1" URI: "C:\BizTalk\Demo-Module6\IN*.xml" *Reason: There was an authentication failure. "Failed to decode the S/MIME message. The S/MIME message may not be valid.".*

XML File :

```
<ns0:ItemList xmlns0:ns0="http://Messaging.InterchangeEnvelope">
    <ns0:ItemHeader>
        <ns0:Sender>Contoso</ns0:Sender>
        <ns0:BatchNumber>125</ns0:BatchNumber>
    </ns0:ItemHeader>
    <ns0:Items>
        <ns0:Item ID="1524856" xmlns:ns0="http://Messaging.InterchangeBody">
            <ns0:QTY>10</ns0:QTY>
            <ns0:Price>30</ns0:Price>
        </ns0:Item>
        <ns0:Item ID="1524857" xmlns:ns0="http://Messaging.InterchangeBody">
            <ns0:QTY>10</ns0:QTY>
            <ns0:Price>40</ns0:Price>
        </ns0:Item>
        <ns0:Item ID="1524858" xmlns:ns0="http://Messaging.InterchangeBody">
            <ns0:QTY>10</ns0:QTY>
            <ns0:Price>50</ns0:Price>
        </ns0:Item>
        <ns0:Item ID="1524859" xmlns:ns0="http://Messaging.InterchangeBody">
            <ns0:QTY>10</ns0:QTY>
            <ns0:Price>60</ns0:Price>
        </ns0:Item>
    </ns0:Items>
</ns0:ItemList>
```

Comment: You talk about Send Pipelines, but you your error message is coming from a receive pipeline.  Also a XML message is not a MIME or SMIME message.  So why are you trying to parse a XML message with a MIME decoder?

Comment: Thank you for response. I have made mistakes with my input file. I think <ns0> ......</ns0>  should be associated with only Target name space lines only(not all lines). Another mistake is Envelope schema was not properly created. I have realized my mistakes by trial and error though it taxed me lot of time but worth learning. Once again thank you.